# Polygon to Raster tool while keeping less than maximum values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, polygon, rasterization

I'm trying to convert a very large, detailed polygon to a raster with a coarser resolution in ArcGIS 10.1 using the polygon to raster tool. The value field is a percentage and the cellsize must be the coarse resolution. My problem comes when I'm trying to choose a cell assignment type. If I choose cell-center or no option I get percentages from 73 to 100, while both maximum and maximum combined area give me roughly 50% and higher. I need the raster to include values of 10% and higher, but I don't know how to accomplish this with the options I have. I've tried making the priority field the percentage as well, but it didn't help.

Comment: Just an update: Using the Minimum Bound Geometry tool I generalized my polygon and then used the polygon to raster tool on that. It gave me percentages from 0 to 100 which is good, but I'm still not sure how to get from 10 to 100. I tried reclassifying, but it doesn't remove the pixels that are less than 10%, it just makes them the same as 10%.